# how I put condition for two attribute in Xpath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

how I can get `PointLocation` by `Xpath` PointBrush which content exactly x and y.
Not: I write `Xpath` inside My `java`.

My Xpath:

```
  NodeList brushNode="PointBrush/PointLocation[x['" + entity.getPointLocation().getX() + "'] | /y['" + entity.getPointLocation().getY() + "']]"
```

my XMl:

```
       <PointBrush>
         <PointLocation>
            <x>36.473796987533674</x>
            <y>35.49325534870742</y>
         </PointLocation>
      </PointBrush>
      <PointBrush>

   <PointBrush>
         <PointLocation>
            <x>36.4723496987533674</x>
            <y>35.1234534870742</y>
         </PointLocation>
      </PointBrush>
      <PointBrush>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be "and y" instead of "| /y"?

Comment: I think you also need to use the "text" function

Answer (score 0):

Based on you needs, you have at least two different choices...

You could use something like...

```
//PointBrush/PointLocation[x[text()='...'] and y[text()='...']]
```

Which will return the `PointBrush` any where within the document, that has a `PointLocation`, that has `x` AND `y` node whose text content matches the values you specify ...

or you could use something like...

```
//PointBrush/PointLocation[x[text()='...']] | //PointBrush/PointLocation[y[text()='...']]
```

Which will return any `PointBrush` that contains a `PointLocation`, that contains either a `x` node whose text content matches the x value OR which has a `y` node whose text context matches the y value...

This is a very important difference, as this will check both the x and y nodes and will return each `PointLocation` that matches EITHER case...

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document dom = db.parse(Test1.class.getResourceAsStream("/Test.xml"));
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    // Find the "thing" node...
    XPathExpression pointBrushExpr = xpath.compile("//PointBrush/PointLocation[x[text()='36.473796987533674'] and y[text()='35.49325534870742']]");
    Node pointBrush = (Node) pointBrushExpr.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODE);

    XPathExpression xExpr = xpath.compile("x");
    Node xNode = (Node) xExpr.evaluate(pointBrush, XPathConstants.NODE);
    XPathExpression yExpr = xpath.compile("y");
    Node yNode = (Node) yExpr.evaluate(pointBrush, XPathConstants.NODE);

    System.out.println(xNode.getTextContent() + " x " + yNode.getTextContent());

    XPathExpression checkExp = xpath.compile("//PointBrush/PointLocation[x[text()='36.473796987533674']] | //PointBrush/PointLocation[y[text()='35.49325534870742']]");
    NodeList check = (NodeList) checkExp.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int index = 0; index < check.getLength(); index++) {
        Node node = check.item(index);
        xExpr = xpath.compile("x");
        xNode = (Node) xExpr.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODE);
        yExpr = xpath.compile("y");
        yNode = (Node) yExpr.evaluate(node, XPathConstants.NODE);

        System.out.println(xNode.getTextContent() + " x " + yNode.getTextContent());
    }

} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```